# Scope of SQL Use statement & Insert Into Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, scope

```
USE DATABASE

insert into #Table   -- Previously created temp table
(
   Name
   Number
   Date  
)  

select 'Joe', 5, 'January 9th' 
union all select 'Sam', 3, 'January 4th'
union all select 'Eleanor', 4, 'January 5th'
union all select 'Joseph', 1, 'January 6th'
```

My question is what is the scope of the USE statement when insert into select is not specifying a 'from' statement that clearly denotes what table in the database the information is coming from?

I've encountered an insert into select statement similar to this one and what I am struggling to understand is if the data is being created in the four select statements or if it is being searched for and found in the DATABASE. If it is being searched for how does Microsoft SQL Server Management studio know what table is being referred to?

Answer (score 1):

Everything following `USE database` will be run in the context of the database chosen.

In this case, the `USE` accomplishes nothing, because your `#temp` table is stored in `tempdb` regardless of which database you're *using*, and your select is not accessing any tables, so it will return the hardcoded values regardless of database context as well.

Comment: The return of hardcoded values is what I needed to know thanks. So regardless of the USE statement in the absence of a from clause the insert into select will just place the hardcoded values into the Table.

Comment: @Zion Yep exactly, also worth noting that you can have as many `USE` statements as you want.  Everything will execute in the currently used db, until the next `USE` statement.  The other option is 3-part naming in your `FROM`, which would be `FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table]`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `FROM` clause, then the data isn't coming from any table in any database.   It is hard-coded into the `INSERT` query.   If you're asking how does it know what table to insert the data into, that is specified in the `INSERT INTO` clause, and is in the context of the `USE` statement.

I'm suspicious of your question, because you insert into a temp table, which you comment as "previously created" and the scope of temp tables is an entirely different matter.

Comment: right above the insert into #Table there is a create table statement where that Table is created.  So without the from statement my understanding is that the select statements are creating the data on those lines and then inserting them into the table, as opposed to finding those values in the database

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.   Why the question?   Are you seeing some unexpected results or errors?

Comment: The full script is quite lengthy, with hundreds of those union all selects, and then furthermore has at least 100 lines of select statements after that each with an obvious 'from" statement denoting where the values are coming from. So i was just thrown off by seeing the first few lines select something without mentioning where it was from.  I'm a relative novice with SQL but am tasked with running what were supposed to be "minor" updates.